# Voice notification management

Tags: text-to-speech

I got a new Galaxy S 2 and played with it a little. Somehow I activated voice notification, so each SMS message I get someone talking and telling me who sent the message. Each phone call, the same.

How to control the activity of this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Samsung device it is:

> Home >> Menu >> Settings >> Voice input and output >> Text-to-speech settings >> Driving mode